# Python no elimina columna de un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Me he creado la siguiente función, el problema que tengo es que cuando llamo a la función, ésta me devuelve un dataframe con la columna '_merge'. No consigo entender por qué me la devuelve si la he eliminado:

```
def drop_outliers(df, column, outliers = None):
    '''
    Elimina filas del DataFrame con valores atípicos presentes en una columna 'column'.
    Por defecto elimina los outliers según el criterio del Rango Intercuartílico pero existe la posibilidad de
    especificar un DataFrame de outliers para eliminar.
    
    Parámetros:
    df -> (Pandas DataFrame)
    column -> (string)
    outliers -> (Pandas DataFrame, opcional)
    return -> Pandas DataFrame sin las filas con valores atípicos en la columna 'column'
    '''
    if outliers is None:
        outliers = get_outliers(df, column)
    df_merged = df.merge(outliers.drop_duplicates(), how='left', on=column, indicator=True)
    df_left = df_merged[df_merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
    df_cleaned = df_left.drop(columns='_merge') # Eliminamos la nueva columna que se ha generado con indicator=True
    return df_cleaned
```

Yo estoy utilizando la función en un Notebook de Jupyter importándola de otro script. Acabo de darme cuenta que cuando la creo en el mismo Notebook funciona correctamente pero cuando la utilizo importándola del script que la contiene no elimina la columna ¿Alguna sugerencia de este comportamiento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con borrar la caché del kernel de Jupiter debería de funcionar. Es un comportamiento normal en la mayoría de cachés que se suele erradicar borrándola.

Comment: Usa algún log para ver los errores que se puedan estar generando. Puede ser quizás también por el entorno o la forma de usarse. Comprueba las versiones de pandas y las bibliotecas o que al importar los scripts no haya errores. Borrar el caché del kernel de Jupiter también puede ayudar

Comment: Al borrar el caché del kernel de Jupyter ha funcionado correctamente, Muchas gracias @DevEzro!!

Comment: @Fernanh98 De nada!! Me alegro mucho de que haya funcionado :)) Voy a editar la respuesta para ayudar al resto que lo necesite